# android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity and com.google.android.gms.maps not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I am sort of new to Android developing. I'm currently using **Android Studio** and I have to use a Google Map in my app. I created the required activity and the default functions were shown, but almost all of these couldn't be resolved. The libraries I'm importing are

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

but neither `FragmentActivity` nor `.maps.` are resolved. I have Google Play Services and Google Repository installed, and

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

in my build.gradle. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try these gradle compile settings. Maybe it will work

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89' // not targeting L Preview
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't. Thanks though.